# How does statement $1$ equate to statement $2$?

Tags: induction

I do not have expert experience in mathematics so I expect the answer to be simple. I'm currently looking into mathematical induction and saw [this problem](http://home.cc.umanitoba.ca/%7Ethomas/Courses/InductionExamples-Solutions.pdf) (Question $2$):

Prove that for n any positive integer: $$6^n −1$$ is divisible by $5$.

The solution shows:

$$6^{k+1} − 1$$
$$= 6(6^k) − 1$$
$$= 6(6^k − 1) − 1 + 6$$
$$= 6(6^k − 1) + 5$$

My question is how does: $$6(6^k) − 1$$ equate to: $$6(6^k − 1) − 1 + 6$$

Comment: Subtract and add a $6$ to get $6(6^k) - 6 + 6 - 1$ and now factor out a $6$.

Comment: Oops, this actually answers the question so it shouldn't belong in the comments.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, use descriptive titles. "How does statement 1 equate to statement 2?" says nothing about the subject of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to see is that when you expand the final expression you have:
$$6(6^k-1)-1+6=6(6^k)-6-1+6=6(6^k)-1$$
Where does this come from? This is a common thing in mathematics, whenever required, we add a "zero". See:
$$6(6^k)-1=6(6^k)+(\color{blue}{-6+6})-1$$
You factor the $6$. (Leave a comment if you don't know what that means.)
$$\implies 6(6^k)-1= 6(6^k-1)+6-1$$
Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)

Comment: Thank you for explaining!

Answer (score 0):

For the $\textbf{induction step},$ you prove that if the statement holds for any given $k$, then it must also hold for the case $k+1$. This is done using the $\textbf{induction hypothesis}.$

Step $1$: Base case. The statement holds for $n=1,2$

Step $2$: Inductive step. Assume that it holds for any arbitrary positive integer $k$, and we show it also holds for $k+1$. Then we use the induction hypothesis, that $6^{k}-1$ is divisible by $5$, to show that $6^{k+1}-1$ is also divisible by $5$. This is why you need to somehow introduce $6^{k}-1$.

$$6^{k+1} − 1$$
$$= 6(6^k) − 1 \quad\textbf{(1)}$$
$$= 6(6^k − 1) − 1 + 6\quad\textbf{(2)}$$
$$= 6(6^k − 1) + 5 \quad\textbf{(3)}$$

In step $\textbf{(1)},$ we have $6^{k}$, but need $6^{k}-1$, so we write $6(6^{k}-1),$ but this gives an extra $-6$. So to remove this error we add $6$ back. Thus we arrive at step $\textbf{(2)},$ which simplifies to the next step, where we then use that induction hypothesis to conclude that $6^{k+1}-1$ is also divisible by $5$.

Since $n=k$ is arbitrary, we conclude that $6^{n}-1$ is divisible by $5$ for any positive integer.